# Google Sheets Addon Trigger Scheduled Updates

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have created an add-on to Google Sheets and published it to the Google Marketplace. It currently allows user fetch data from our system and have it easily flow into their spreadsheet. They begin by saving an API key (which I stored in a user property) then request data from our system. The API Key to understand which customer has made the request, and return only their data, which is added to their spreadsheet.

This is working well  Now I'd like to make the data refresh automatically once a day. I've been looking into time based triggers and they seem like what I need, but there are a few tricky bits I haven't figured out. When my app is published to the Google Marketplace I believe that each user is just accessing the single project. I was originally thinking of creating a scheduled trigger for each customer (that way they could opt-in/out and configure the frequency of the updates), but I'm struggling with the shared context.

Setting up a time based trigger you can specify the function name but it doesn't seem like you can pass any parameter values to be used when trigger is created. I'm unsure of the execution context that will be available when the function runs. My function needs to know two things (the API key for the customer, and the spreadsheet for the data to be placed into).

I guess the question is whether there is any context available at the time the job is triggered?  If not, how should I think about tackling this problem?

UPDATE: A little more [reading here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) makes me think that a trigger may actually be tied to the document and the user that executed the code that created the trigger.

Comment: Sounds like you could use propertiesService for that.  If the data sheet is different for each customer then you could create an object whose property is customer name and the output would be an object that contain API  Key and data sheet name